# Creating a array of 1s and 0s using another array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have two arrays (row and column) `row = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4]` and `column = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 4]`

I want to use the rows and columns arrays to insert the value "1" into another 2D array (vectors)

```
vectors = 
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

so my desired output is:

```
vectors = 
[[1. 1. 1. 0. 0.],
[1. 0. 1. 1. 0.],
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 0. 1. 1. 0.],
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Sorry if my explanation is bad it's my first time using python and Stackoverflow.

Comment: what is the logic? vectors is 5*5 but row, column is 12*12

Comment: What's the logic behind this?

Comment: @Epsi95 I am creating a vector from those values so I need to use the rows and columns to show the position where to add the 1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `row` and `column` vector as indices:

```
>>> vectors[row, column] = 1
>>> vectors
array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: Oh wow, it was that simple thanks for the help; I need to work on my python skills.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try this:

```
for r, c in zip(row, column):
    vectors[r][c] = 1
```

Comment: no problem!  Actually, I learned a little something from @Cyttorak's answer, too, so that's a bonus.